# как сделать остановку слайдера при наведении мыши на него?

Tags: javascript, html, css

как сделать остановку слайдера при наведении мыши на него?

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

/* Функция увеличивает индекс на 1, показывает следующй слайд*/
function plusSlide() {
    showSlides(slideIndex += 1);
}

/* Функция уменьшяет индекс на 1, показывает предыдущий слайд*/
function minusSlide() {
    showSlides(slideIndex -= 1);  
}

/* Устанавливает текущий слайд */
function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

/* Основная функция слайдера */
function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-dots_item");
    if (n > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
setInterval(plusSlide, 4000);
```

```css
 /* Собственно сам слайдер */
.slider {
   overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

/* Картинка мастабируется по отношению к родительскому элементу */
.slider .item img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

/* Кнопки вперед и назад */
.slider .prev, .slider .next {
    cursor: pointer;
   position: absolute;
   width: auto;
    top: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 18px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.slider .next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.slider .prev {
  left: 10px;
}

/* При наведении на кнопки добавляем фон кнопок */
.slider .prev:hover,
.slider .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Заголовок слайда */
.slideText {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 35px;

    /* Выравнивание текста по горизонтали и по вертикали */
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    /* Тень */
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000, 0 0 1em #000;
}

/* Кружочки */
.slider-dots {
    text-align: center;
}

.slider-dots_item {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.slider-dots_item:hover {
    background-color: #aaa;
}

/* Анимация слайдов */
.slider .item {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: 0.4;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: 0.4;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
<div class="item"><a href="#"><img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/33827/e27a7c31-aa08-4b03-bf93-c6ec7c7e1857/s1200" alt="Первый слайд" /></a></div>
<div class="item"><a href="#"><img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/33827/e27a7c31-aa08-4b03-bf93-c6ec7c7e1857/s1200" alt="Второй слайд" /></a></div>
<div class="item"><a href="#"><img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/33827/e27a7c31-aa08-4b03-bf93-c6ec7c7e1857/s1200" alt="Третий слайд" /></a></div>
<div class="item"><a href="#"><img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/33827/e27a7c31-aa08-4b03-bf93-c6ec7c7e1857/s1200" alt="Четвертый слайд" /></a></div>
<a class="prev" onclick="minusSlide()">❮</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlide()">❯</a></div>
<div class="slider-dots"><span class="slider-dots_item" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> <span class="slider-dots_item" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> <span class="slider-dots_item" onclick="currentSlide(3)"> </span> <span class="slider-dots_item" onclick="currentSlide(4)"> </span></div>
```

Comment: У вас слайд срабатывает в конце за счет setInterval 4000... ну вот там можно вместо этих 4000 записать переменную. Которая изначально равна 4000. А при наведении становится 999999 (не остановка, а тупо много). Он еще к классам привязан... 'mouseenter' может убрать классы откуда надо и сломать слайдер. А 'mouseleave' - вернуть классы на место.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME то что Вы предложили - не сработает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно добавить что то такое

```
 var hover;   

 document.querySelector('.slider')
   .addEventListener('mousemove', () => hover = 1);

 document.querySelector('.slider')
   .addEventListener('mouseout', () => hover = 0);

setInterval(() => !hover && plusSlide(), 4000);
```

и убрать это

```
  setInterval(plusSlide, 4000);
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!

Comment: Все поставил, еще раз спасибо!